# Javascript Number Formatting

Tags: javascript

Certainly a stupid question, please forgive me. My customer wants decimal numbers to display with five digits. For example: 100.34 or 37.459. I was accomplishing this with `val.toPrecision (5);`; however, when my numbers get really small, I stop getting what I want. For example, if my number is 0.000347, it displays 0.00034700. Now, I understand why it's doing this, but what I don't know is how to get it to display 0.0003. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format  and the first answer's sprintf link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our problem is with numbers less than 1 obviously. So catch them and deal them separately

```
function SetPrecisionToFive(n){  
    return (n > 1) ? n.toPrecision (5) : (Math.round(n * 1e4) / 1e4).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Math.round(0.000347 * 1e4) / 1e4
```

Or with `toFixed`:

```
Number.prototype.toNDigits = function (n) {
    return (Math.abs(this) < 1) ?
        this.toFixed(n - 1) :
        this.toPrecision(n);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HeQtH/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toFixed method to accomplish this. For example: `(0.000347).toFixed(4)`

Comment: Will toFixed change 100.34298 to 100.34 as he wants?

Comment: jQuery for `toFixed`, are you kidding?

Comment: Why would you need to be using jQuery to use `toFixed`?

Comment: oh pal. just leave jquery once in a while :)

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

The Javascript toFixed() function will truncate small numbers to a fixed decimal precision, eg:

```
var num = .0000350;
var result = num.toFixed(5); // result will equal .00003
```

Comment: Now do `(100.34).toFixed(5)`.

Comment: @katspaugh this code snippet would be conditional... not meant to cover all cases